# Rx with external states

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Rx with external states?

So in this example there is Rx functionality combined with external state full behavior.
What is the best approach with Rx to achieve this?

Problematic code places are with 'updateActive'.

```
public enum Source
{
    Observable1,
    Observable2,
}

// Type is Source.Observable1
IObservable<Source> observable1;

// Type is Source.Observable2
IObservable<Source> observable2;

var mergedObservables = observable1.Select(x => Source.Observable1)
    .Merge(observable2.Select(x => Source.Observable2));

var updateActive = false;

mergedObservables.Subscribe(x =>
{
    switch (x.Source)
    {
        case Source.Observable1:
        {
            if (updateActive)
                break;

            updateActive = true;

            // Here is some code which causes that observable2 will get some new values. 
            // (this coud be also on an other thread)
            // If this is the case, the new value(s) should be ignored.

            updateActive = false;
        }
        break;

        case Source.Observable2:
        {
            if (updateActive)
                break;

            updateActive = true;

            // Here is some code which causes that observable1 will get some new values. 
            // (this coud be also on an other thread)
            // If this is the case, the new value(s) should be ignored.

            updateActive = false;
        }
        break;
    }
});
```

Remarks: How can i transport the 'updateActive' state within Rx operators

Comment: Why do you merge these two streams if you then going to separate the logic through a switch statement?

Comment: That was the initial idea to merge them so it could be handled through Rx operators. If there would be 2 separate streams then it is just like normal event processing and i want to avoid this. To precise the question: How can i transport the 'updateActive' state within Rx operators.

Comment: Technically, this approach is perfectly reasonable as long as you lock `updateActive` in the right places. What does the ommitted code look like? Is the ongoing work represented by a `Task`-object? If so, I could think of a way to do this.

Comment: The omitted code can be very complicated. In some cases it could be a task in some cases it could be the 'observable2 or observable1' source with modified operations, so if some one redefines the scheduler then it is hard to await the correct behavior. So i think to avoid all the side-effects would be to have a possibility to transport the state within all the operators.

Comment: Try to represent the update as a task. The IsCompleted-property will be your `updateActive`. Then you might be able to carry these task around as state in a `Scan`-operation.

Comment: Can you please clarify if you are setting the `updateActive` so that you don't have more than one update occurring at a time?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an instance of `Subject<bool>` as a state carrier.

Given:

```
Subject<bool> isUpdating = new Subject<bool>();
```

You will use it in something like this:

```
var flaggedObservables = mergedObservables
    .CombineLatest(isUpdating, (obs, flag) => new {obs, IsUpdating = flag});

flaggedObservables
    .Where(data => !data.IsUpdating)
    .Select(data => data.obs)
    .DistinctUntilChanged()
    .Subscribe(
        obs =>
        {
            isUpdating.OnNext(true);

            //do some work on obs

            isUpdating.OnNext(false);
        });
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but it ended up in an endless loop.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Try it with the `DistinctUntilChanged` call, as it appears now.

Comment: @Saqib: This solves the problem of the mutable variable `updateActive`, however, as Erik Meijer puts it in https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bbf87eea-6a17-4920-96d7-2131e397a234/why-does-emeijer-not-like-subjects, "[Subjects] are the "mutable variables" of the Rx world".

Comment: @Bluesman well, there is nothing to do about it. In this case you have to use some mechanism involving side effects. I don't see how to solve this concrete problem in a pure functional way.

Comment: @galenus This also produces endless loops. And i think i have to create a new operator which encapsulate this behavior. For example as extension method "AvoidFeedbackMerge".

Comment: @Saqib this will produce endless loops only in case your `Source` is not an enum, but something else, `Equals` of which returns `false` for two identical values.

Answer (score 0):

If you got a `Task`that represents the updating, this might actually work (although I don't know if I captured your desired semantics here correctly because from your initial post it seems you're ignoring all elements from the source anyway).

```
public enum Source
{
    Observable1,
    Observable2,
}

// Type is Source.Observable1
IObservable<Source> observable1;

// Type is Source.Observable2
IObservable<Source> observable2;

var mergedObservables = observable1.Select(x => Source.Observable1)
    .Merge(observable2.Select(x => Source.Observable2));

mergedObservables 
    .Scan(
        new
        {
            Value = (Source?)null,
            CurrentUpdateTask = (Task)null
        },
        (tuple, value)
        {
            if ((tuple.CurrentUpdateTask == null) || (tuple.CurrentUpdateTask.IsCompleted))
            {
                // No update running. Start updating.
                return new
                {
                    Value = value,
                    CurrentUpdateTask = Update()  //Some Task-returning method that does the update.
                };
            }

            // Update in flight. Ignore value.
            return new
            {
                Value = (Source?)null,
                tuple.CurrentUpdateTask
            };
        })
    .Where(tuple => tuple.Value.HasValue)
    .Select(tuple.Value.Value)
    .Subscribe(...);
```

Comment: This also will produce endless loops, because of cross feedback into observabales.

Comment: What causes the feedback?

Comment: sorry i must correct, it "could" produce endless loops. Because you do not have enough information how the 2 merged observable sources are connected to each other. So for example: you are in context of stream from observable1 and in the Update method some data could be produced which will effect the stream of observable2.

Comment: Since Rx-methods are not reentrant (i.e. you will not observe a new value while processing the old one has not finished) this should not feedback endlessly. But I feel your Update-procedure and your architecture is way to complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `Where` clauses to your `observable1` and `observable2`.  Use `System.Threading.Interlocked` to  ensure the value of `isActive` propagated to the other threads.  Note that there is always a race condition where a value could arrive on both observable simultaneously.  Both will end up executing, though not concurrently.  This code only stops values that come through that were generated while the value was true.

// Type is Source.Observable1
    IObservable observable1;

```
// Type is Source.Observable2
IObservable<Source> observable2;

int isActive = 0;

var mergedObservables = Observable.Merge(
    observable1
        .Where(t => Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref isActive, 1, 2) == 0)
        .Select(x => Source.Observable1),
    observable2
        .Where(t => Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref isActive, 1, 2) == 0)
        .Select(x => Source.Observable2));

mergedObservables.Subscribe(x =>
{
    switch (x.Source)
    {
        case Source.Observable1:
        {
            Interlocked.Exchange(ref isActive, 1);

            // Here is some code which causes that observable2 will get some new values. 
            // (this coud be also on an other thread)
            // If this is the case, the new value(s) should be ignored.

            Interlocked.Exchange(ref isActive, 0);
        }
        break;

        case Source.Observable2:
        {
            Interlocked.Exchange(ref isActive, 1);

            // Here is some code which causes that observable1 will get some new values. 
            // (this coud be also on an other thread)
            // If this is the case, the new value(s) should be ignored.

            Interlocked.Exchange(ref isActive, 0);
        }
        break;
    }
});
```